# How to make a line with multiple colors using CAShapeLayer and UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

Suppose I want to make a drawing that looks like this (pardon my bad drawing):

[image: Line with multiple colors]

As you can see here, I want to make a line that has multiple colors on the line. What I did now is make a the line using `UIBezierPath` for the path and use `CAShapeLayer` to render the drawing. But I don't know how to set the colors for the shape layer. Since the lines could have multiple colors, I've researched some answers but most of the answers that I found told me to create a `CAGradientLayer` and make the shape layer as a mask of that gradient layer like this (not the full code because some of them are confidential):

```
// This function is from a library we used.
import UIKit

struct CurvedSegment {
    var controlPoint1: CGPoint
    var controlPoint2: CGPoint
}

class CurveAlgorithm {
    static let shared = CurveAlgorithm()
    
    public func controlPointsFrom(points: [CGPoint]) -> [CurvedSegment] {
        var result: [CurvedSegment] = []
        
        let delta: CGFloat = 0.3 // The value that help to choose temporary control points.
        
        // Calculate temporary control points, these control points make Bezier segments look straight and not curving at all
        for i in 1..<points.count {
            let A = points[i-1]
            let B = points[i]
            let controlPoint1 = CGPoint(x: A.x + delta*(B.x-A.x), y: A.y + delta*(B.y - A.y))
            let controlPoint2 = CGPoint(x: B.x - delta*(B.x-A.x), y: B.y - delta*(B.y - A.y))
            let curvedSegment = CurvedSegment(controlPoint1: controlPoint1, controlPoint2: controlPoint2)
            result.append(curvedSegment)
        }
        
        // Calculate good control points
        for i in 1..<points.count-1 {
            /// A temporary control point
            let M = result[i-1].controlPoint2
            
            /// A temporary control point
            let N = result[i].controlPoint1
            
            /// central point
            let A = points[i]
            
            /// Reflection of M over the point A
            let MM = CGPoint(x: 2 * A.x - M.x, y: 2 * A.y - M.y)
            
            /// Reflection of N over the point A
            let NN = CGPoint(x: 2 * A.x - N.x, y: 2 * A.y - N.y)
            
            result[i].controlPoint1 = CGPoint(x: (MM.x + N.x)/2, y: (MM.y + N.y)/2)
            result[i-1].controlPoint2 = CGPoint(x: (NN.x + M.x)/2, y: (NN.y + M.y)/2)
        }
        
        return result
    }
    
    /**
     Create a curved bezier path that connects all points in the dataset
     */
    func createCurvedPath(_ dataPoints: [CGPoint]) -> UIBezierPath? {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: dataPoints[0])
        
        var curveSegments: [CurvedSegment] = []
        curveSegments = controlPointsFrom(points: dataPoints)
        
        for i in 1..<dataPoints.count {
            path.addCurve(to: dataPoints[i], controlPoint1: curveSegments[i-1].controlPoint1, controlPoint2: curveSegments[i-1].controlPoint2)
        }
        return path
    }
}

func createLineDrawing(points: [CGPoint], colors: [CGColor]) {
        self.curveBezierPath = createCurvedPath(points)
        
        let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = createGradientLayerWithColors(colors: colors)
        gradientLayer.frame = layer.bounds

        let shapeMask = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeMask.path = curveBezierPath?.cgPath
        shapeMask.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        shapeMask.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeMask.lineWidth = somelineWidth

        gradientLayer.mask = shapeMask
    }
```

The result of this code is not what I want to achieve, because the colors of the line will move vertically and don't follow the line's path like the example drawing above. Is there any other way to achieve this? I want to keep using the `UIBezierPath` to achieve the smoothness of line edges (because `UIBezierPath` has the `addCurve` method).

TLDR; Is there anyway to set multiple colors to a `CAShapeLayer` without using `CAGradientLayer` as the background of the shape layer (also the shape layer as the mask of that gradient layer)?

Comment: Let's step back and figure out what you are really trying to achieve before we focus on a specific solution. What result do you want? Do you want a UIImage creating with a drawing of the points and colors? Do you want a UIView's `draw` method to draw the points and colors? Or something other final result?

Comment: OK but that doesn't answer my question. What end result do you need? Perhaps it would help to show a bit more code. Show how you are trying to use the result of your `createLineDrawing` method.

Comment: So it sounds like you just need to implement the `draw` method of your custom UIView so it draws the curve based on its current points and colors. Update your question with your `createCurvedPath` method.

Comment: The biggest issue with your question is that you still haven't made it clear what you are using the result for. What do you plan to do with the CAShapeLayer? Or the view? That needs to be in your question. The `createCurvedPath` method needs to be in your question. Show what your goal is so people can provide a solution that meets your goal. Focusing on the shape layer is potentially leading you down the wrong path. And how can `draw` being any more expensive than calling your `createLineDrawing` anytime you want to add another point/color?

Comment: You misunderstand. I'm asking for you to explain, technically, how the resulting drawn curve will be used. You don't need to get into confidential info. Just describe at a high level how the result will be used. As I said, are you earlier, are you just creating a custom view that shows the curve? Are you creating an image? Show more of the class that contains the `createLineDrawing` method. You don't need to show secrets, just show some scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
If this is what you're looking for..

One way to achieve this is by splitting the UIBezierPath into segments and drawing each segment using a separate CAShapeLayers.

However, splitting a UIBezierPath isn't that straightforward...
The most complex part is splitting the curves so that each next segment is the exact continuation of the previous segment to get a smooth drawing like the original one. You will need advanced knowledge of UIBezierPath and how it works etc.. Or, you can simply use the gist I shared...

Here is the code (from the pic):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Initialize UIBezierPath extension
        UIBezierPath.sp_prepare()
    }
}

class SolidColorLinesView: UIView {

    //Original shape, drawn in solid black
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()

    //Segment shapes, each draw in a unique color
    var segmentShapes = [CAShapeLayer]()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    func createOriginalPath() -> UIBezierPath {
        let shape = UIBezierPath()
        shape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 394))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 258),
                       controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 53.33, y: 372.33),
                       controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 166.4, y: 314.8))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 142, y: 1),
                       controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 242, y: 187),
                       controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 206, y: 3))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 7, y: 118),
                       controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 78, y: -1),
                       controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 3, y: 13))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 156, y: 202),
                       controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 11, y: 223),
                       controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 136, y: 229))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 171, y: 76),
                       controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 176, y: 175),
                       controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 106))
        shape.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 76, y: 94),
                       controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 142, y: 46),
                       controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 77, y: 54))
        return shape
    }

    func configShapeLayer(layer shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer, with path: UIBezierPath, color: UIColor = UIColor.black, width: CGFloat = 10) {
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = width
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let originalPath = createOriginalPath()
        configShapeLayer(layer: shape, with: originalPath)
        if shape.superlayer == nil {
            layer.addSublayer(shape)
        }

        //Clear all old drawings
        segmentShapes.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperlayer() })
        segmentShapes.removeAll()

        //Splits the original path into 5 parts (4 dividers).
        let segmentsToSplit: [CGFloat] = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]
        let colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .yellow, .cyan, .magenta]
        let splitPaths = originalPath.split(segments: segmentsToSplit)
        for (index, path) in splitPaths.enumerated() {
            let layer = CAShapeLayer()
            segmentShapes.append(layer)
            configShapeLayer(layer: layer, with: path, color: colors[index], width: 4)
            self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        }
    }
}
```

Gist: [UIBezierPath+Superpowers](https://gist.github.com/arturdev/240bb3977cdb0408706679a57adaf310)

========

If you want to draw gradient lines instead of solid colors, it will require a more complex approach (which might be less performant).. for example, iterate over "all" (or every 3-4) the points of the path and draw the pixels in a desired (interpolated) color you want. The lower you choose the pixel groups, the smoother will be the color gradient, though the less will be performance... so not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try the below code

```
//
//  ToDo:  you need to save the points to persist the line.
//
import SwiftUI

struct ColoredLineDrawingView: View {
    @State private var points: [CGPoint] = []
    @State private var colors: [Color] = [Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Path { path in
                    if let firstPoint = points.first {
                        path.move(to: firstPoint)
                        for point in points {
                            path.addLine(to: point)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .stroke(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: colors), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing), lineWidth: 5)
                .background(Color.white)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .onChanged { value in
                            let point = value.location
                            points.append(point)
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            points = []
                        }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct ColoredLineDrawingApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ColoredLineDrawingView()
        }
    }
}
```